# Intermittent compilation failure without changing the source code

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm compiling a program that I have recompiled after every rustup update, (without changing the program) without problems.

I'm getting this issue with `cargo run` where it will crash out of compiling, but when I press "up+enter" to run the same command it will usually compile a little further into the program: e.g.

```
$ cargo run
   <snip: Compiling ...>
   Compiling rust-ini v0.15.3
error: could not compile `syn`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name syn --edition=2018 ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.38/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="clone-impls"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="derive"' --cfg 'feature="full"' --cfg 'feature="parsing"' --cfg 'feature="printing"' --cfg 'feature="proc-macro"' --cfg 'feature="quote"' --cfg 'feature="visit"' -C metadata=0c8657072ce319aa -C extra-filename=-0c8657072ce319aa --out-dir ~/rust/Projects/e2/target/release/deps -L dependency=~/rust/Projects/e2/target/release/deps --extern proc_macro2=~/rust/Projects/e2/target/release/deps/libproc_macro2-368f1cdc954709ae.rmeta --extern quote=~/rust/Projects/e2/target/release/deps/libquote-228036b67939ecd8.rmeta --extern unicode_xid=~/rust/Projects/e2/target/release/deps/libunicode_xid-12e7836b5e556b0a.rmeta --cap-lints allow` (signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

```
$ cargo run 
   Compiling syn v1.0.38
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.115
   Compiling serde v1.0.115
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.57
   Compiling serde_stacker v0.1.4
   Compiling serde_yaml v0.8.13
error: could not compile `serde_json`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name serde_json --edition=2018 
<snip: same as previous> 
--cfg limb_width_64` (signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
$ cargo run
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.57
...
```

(this time serde_json compiles)

I'm starting to wonder if the RAM in my computer is dodgy. I'm waiting for memtest86+ on Debian to play nicely with UEFI.

Is this a known issue with:

```
cargo 1.52.0-nightly (90691f2bf 2021-03-16)
```

or

```
rustc 1.53.0-nightly (07e0e2ec2 2021-03-24)
```

?

Comment: *the RAM in my computer is dodgy* — that was my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

I have met same question and `cargo clean` didn't works. I solved it by clean memory cache with `echo 3 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` finally.